# Azure DevOps - Azure Resource Group Deployment: set value of subscription dynamically

Tags: configuration, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure Resource Group Deployment Task that deploys an Azure Key Vault. To configure the task I have a config file where each value in this config file is environment-dependently converted to an environment variable. But when I want to use a variable in field `Azure subscription` I get the error `##[error]Error: Task failed while initializing. Error: Endpoint auth data not present: <endpointName>` If I hardcode the value into the task the deployment works (i.e. the usage of variables in the other fields like `Resource group` is possible).

[image]

Is the usage of a variable for `Azure subscription` just not possible or is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: i suggest you run the build once for each subscription you want to run it against (without variable) and convert to variable after

Comment: Thank you for your response. My goal is that I have a single config file in the repository that defines all the values for the pipeline. I.e. in the end `$(serviceEndpoint)` is an environment variable that contains the name of the service endpoint. In this context I don't understand what you exactly mean. Furthermore this is a task in the Release not Build. Can you please describe it a bit more?

Comment: i dont think it matters. whats happens when you run it manually without a variable - it will create a authentication for your release to that azure subscription (not in azure, but inside vsts). so try doing that and convert to variable after

Comment: No this does not work unfortunately. I tried it (in the context of a Release) first hardcoded and then with the variable. I also tried to hardcode it into the first azure resource deployment task and use the variable in a subsequent one... Maybe other suggestions? Or does it work for you?

Comment: it kinda works for me with yaml builds (there are not yaml releases yet). cant help you if that advice doesnt work. sorry

Comment: I also tried now to use the id of the service endpoint respectively the service principal but this also does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do that. It has to be selected manually. If someone has a better answer please share.